# Run a program or method at specific time in Java

Tags: java, scheduling

I just want that my program or method should run at specific date and time.
i have heard about Timer and TimerTask in java API. But don't know exactly how to use it.

Comment: "program or method"? Which is it, a program or a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a java program at a specific time you probably want to look at the OS tools (like cron or at).

If you want to run a method inside of an already running java application then the [ScheduleExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), while it may be overkill, is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for your own benefit and not for a project I would suggest you look into 
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html which is a replacement for java.util.Timer. If however you want a robust scheduler, I concur with the previous posters with regards to Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a third-party library with a higher level API like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) and use the [SimpleTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson05.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can run your task inside a [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) Java EE server.  It supports a Timer Service that fires background tasks at specified intervals.  When you're running a cluster of Glassfish servers on different machines, they'll collaborate to fire the task exactly once.

A simpler approach is to rely on `cron` for Unix systems.  At specified times you can run your java task via the `java` command.

I've also used [pycron](http://www.kalab.com/freeware/pycron/pycron.htm) on Windows, which is a service that emulates `cron`.