# How to execute the code at particular time in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer

I have requirement saying that i want execute the mailing code without any event but based on timer when the specified time comes that code as to execute and the mail has to send .

```
package com.uttara.reg;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class Timer extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

i can't understand how to call timer class

Could anybody plz help me out!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201197/run-a-java-program-in-specific-time  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488736/run-a-program-or-method-at-specific-time-in-java

Comment: form where to call the   Timer timer = new Timer();  in servlet

Answer (score 2):

you can try a few things

1 : Timer class

2 : TimerTask class

3 : Quartz

4 : Cron

5 : Scheduler

or if you have a very simple requirement then

step 1 : create a thread to get time

step 2 : in the thread keep

```
if(time_by_thread == time_want_to_execute)
{
//execute your timer code here
}
```

Comment: could u plz explain me how to do with servlet

Comment: well i would suggest you search a little about web services , creating a servlet directly for your response it not considered good

Answer (score 0):

check out Timer and Scheduler classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Timer as follows:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
       // Your code
       }
    }, your delay);
```

Or

```
// creating timer task, timer
      TimerTask tasknew = new TimerScheduleDelay();
      Timer timer = new Timer();

      // scheduling the task at interval
      timer.schedule(tasknew, 100);      
   }

   // this method performs the task
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("timer working");      
   }
```

This should be separated from a Java EE app server. You can use Quartz, or an operating system scheduled task, or a batch manager i.e. AutoSys, but implementing it into a servlet is not preferable and usefull to me.
Java EE have a TimerService you can use that.

Comment: how to create class fro this

Comment: You dont need to create separate class for this...
just go through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java

Comment: Timer timer = new Timer(); where do i create it becz am using it j2ee application

Comment: this link can help you: http://www.onjava.com/2004/10/13/j2ee-timers.html

Comment: really i can't understand am very new to it,could u plz explain me how to do with servlet